# why do I keep getting prompted to confirm?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to install `Install-Module -Name SqlServer -confirm:$false` on many servers. I am running this as Admin

however i keep getting a prompt to confirm even though I have specified `-confirm:$false`

```
NuGet provider is required to continue
PowerShellGet requires NuGet provider version '2.8.5.201' or newer to interact with NuGet-based repositories. The NuGet
 provider must be available in 'C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies' or
'C:\Users\\AppData\Local\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies'. You can also install the NuGet provider by
running 'Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force'. Do you want PowerShellGet to install
and import the NuGet provider now?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

I also tried `-force` instead, and same thing, it keep prompting me to confirm...

This will not be ideal because if i want to use a script to install the module, i will have to be there to confirm, which defeats the purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its complicated; the module you are asking to install has a dependency on the `NuGet` package provider, and its not supressing the prompt for the *installation of the dependency*.

However... you can just run this first:

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
```

And then you should be fine!

Comment: ok now i am getting this Untrusted repository
You are installing the modules from an untrusted repository. If you trust this repository, change its
InstallationPolicy value by running the Set-PSRepository cmdlet. Are you sure you want to install the modules from
'PSGallery'?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"):

Comment: Try `Set-PSRepository -Name PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted`

Comment: If someone can't run this command, try this one: `Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Install-PackageProvider NuGet -Force
Set-PSRepository PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted
Install-Module SqlServer -Confirm:$False -Force
```